# Linting error after upgrading Angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular9

Got errors while running "npm run lint" command:

```
src/translations/en-US.json[1, 1]: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call
src/translations/en-US.json[2, 3]: " should be '
src/translations/en-US.json[13, 2]: Missing semicolon
```

Content of en-US.json:

```
{
  "APP_NAME": "test-project",
  "About": "About",
}
```

Tried applying few things in the tslint.json file will not resolving the same.

Comment: `src/translations/en-US.json[2, 3]: " should be '`

Did you tried to change double quotes by single quotes ? I'm not sure about errors, but....

Comment: @NRE:  yes, I tried the command ng lint --fix too that changed it to replace double with single quote and place a semicolon at the end, but then json format start giving an error not considering it as a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

We can ignore linting rule for the translation files using the following command:

```
"ng lint --exclude \"src/translations/*.json\""
```

Thanks